# Shortcut for inspecting HTML documents in Safari 4

Tags: safari, shortcut

Can't find the shortcut for clicking on the magnifying glass for inspecting HTML elements in Safari 4. Any idea on this? (or any resource with a complete list of the web development shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

try using this : Cmd-Option-V

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for me  (although cmd + alt + i brings up the development console ..). any idea why?